# validate password and confirmpassword

Tags: flutter, api, validation

can we validate password and confirmpassword by this method?

```
SizedBox(
  height: 55,
  child: MyTextField(
      controller: TextEditingController(text: user.password),
      validator: _validatePassword,
      hintText: 'Password',
      obsecureText: true,
      icon: const Icon(null)),
),
const SizedBox(
  height: 15,
),
SizedBox(
  height: 55,
  child: MyTextField(
      controller: TextEditingController(text: user.confirmPassword),
      validator: (val) {
        if (val!.isEmpty) {
          return 'Empty';
        } else if (val != user.password) {
          return 'Not Match';
        }
      },
      hintText: 'Confirm Password',
      obsecureText: true,
      icon: const Icon(null)),
),
const SizedBox(height: 30),
```

I tried to do it with controller but cannot link it with the API calling

Answer (score 1):

You can create two separate different controllers for each and then check if those are having same text.  like

```dart
final passWordController = TextEditingController();

final confirmPassWordController = TextEditingController();
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 55,
          child: TextFormField(
            controller: passWordController,
            validator: (value) {
                // .... others validator
                if (passWordController.text ==
                    confirmPassWordController.text) {
                  return "password didnt match";
                }
            },
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 15,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 55,
          child: TextFormField(
              controller: confirmPassWordController,
              validator: (val) {
                
              // .... others validator
                if (passWordController.text ==
                    confirmPassWordController.text) {
                  return "password didnt match";
                }
              }),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 30),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```